# R - analyzing 2 by 2 table of categorical data

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a small data set of cases from an outbreak. For each case I have collected data for a few variables (age, HIV status, hospitalisation, country of infection etc. ). There are only 28 cases and so I imagine that it won't be possible to do any meaningful inferential statistical analysis. I would however like to present the data in as scientific manner as possible.

I would like to, for example, tabulate the data showing the difference between the cases that are HIV positive and HIV negative. I've included some R script and the results of what I've managed to do so far:

```
data <- read.csv("Shigella.csv")
library(dplyr)
library(epiR)
data$Hospitalised <- factor(data$Hospitalised, levels = c("Yes", "No"), labels = c("Hospitalised", "Not Hospitalised"))
data$HIV <- factor(data$HIV, levels = c("Positive", "Negative"))
ttab <- table(data$Hospitalised, data$HIV)
ttab


                   Positive Negative
  Hospitalised            2        1
  Not Hospitalised       13       11


Odds_Ratio <- epi.2by2(ttab, method = "case.control", conf.level = 0.95)
Odds_Ratio

> Odds_Ratio
             Outcome +    Outcome -      Total        Prevalence *        Odds
Exposed +            2            1          3                66.7        2.00
Exposed -           13           11         24                54.2        1.18
Total               15           12         27                55.6        1.25
Point estimates and 95 % CIs:
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Odds ratio (W)                               1.69 (0.13, 21.27)
Attrib prevalence *                          12.50 (-44.45, 69.45)
Attrib prevalence in population *            1.39 (-25.97, 28.75)
Attrib fraction (est) in exposed  (%)        39.79 (-1206.69, 99.08)
Attrib fraction (est) in population (%)      5.45 (-22.83, 27.23)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 X2 test statistic: 0.169 p-value: 0.681
 Wald confidence limits
 * Outcomes per 100 population units
```

From the above, my interpreting is that the odds of a hospitalised case being HIV postive are 1.69 that of a non-hospitalised case being HIV positive. The 95% CI is (0.13, 21.27).

I am not sure that the p value is however. I see a p value of 0.681 but that seems to be for the X2 value.

Here is what I'm stuck with: 
1) am I using the right statistical test (or should I be doing logistic regression or something else)? 
2) how do I get a p value for the odds ratio (or is the p value provided above actually for the odds ratio)?

With appreciation!

Greg

Comment: You have a contingency table and conduct a chi-squared test. With the stats package: `chisq.test(cbind(c(2, 13), c(1, 11)), simulate.p.value = TRUE)`. The `X2` is actually a $\chi^2$, i.e., the test statistic. Your p-value tells you that you can't reject the null that the observed difference is due to chance.

Comment: The Fisher exact test is another potential test to use

Comment: An odds ratio of 1 would mean that you have an even chance of having HIV with or without being hospitalised. Since your confidence interval contains 1, you don't have any evidence that it makes a difference. As @Roland says, the X2 is the chi-squared. Looking at your data, you only have 3 hospitalised cases: 2 with and 1 without.

Comment: Although you could use logistic regression it would not add anything here (at least in my view). I think you just present your results and say why you cannot collect any more cases.